# Why is my email implementation using the local user instead of the assigned the smtp user?

Tags: java, email

I'm debugging my email implementation that used to work and decided to rule out smtp server problems. I found [this crunchify](http://crunchify.com/java-mailapi-example-send-an-email-via-gmail-smtp/) tutorial on implementing `java mail` on gmail.

I somewhat tuned it to my needs, but the application uses my local machine user and host instead of the given in the code.

```
static Properties mailServerProperties;
static Session getMailSession;
static MimeMessage generateMailMessage;

public static void main(String args[]) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    generateAndSendEmail();
    System.out.println("\n\n ===> Your Java Program has just sent an Email successfully. Check your email..");
}

public static void generateAndSendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

    // Step1
    System.out.println("\n 1st ===> setup Mail Server Properties..");
    mailServerProperties = System.getProperties();
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    System.out.println("Mail Server Properties have been setup successfully..");

    // Step2
    System.out.println("\n\n 2nd ===> get Mail Session..");
    getMailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailServerProperties, null);
    generateMailMessage = new MimeMessage(getMailSession);
    generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("destination@email.com"));
    generateMailMessage.setSubject("Greetings");
    String emailBody = "Test email";
    generateMailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");
    System.out.println("Mail Session has been created successfully..");

    // Step3
    System.out.println("\n\n 3rd ===> Get Session and Send mail");
    Transport transport = getMailSession.getTransport("smtp");

    // Enter your correct UserID and Password
    // if you have 2FA enabled then provide App Specific Password
    transport.connect("smtp.server.com", 587, "sender@email.com", "password");

    transport.sendMessage(generateMailMessage, generateMailMessage.getAllRecipients());

    transport.close();
}
```

The console error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 504 5.5.2 <gtl@giedi-prime>: Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1862)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1118)
at br.com.mentium.hrm.agent.utils.Emailer.generateAndSendEmail(Emailer.java:247)
at br.com.mentium.hrm.agent.utils.Emailer.main(Emailer.java:215)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 504 5.5.2 <gtl@giedi-prime>: Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1762)
... 3 more
```

How to fix it?

Comment: So where in that code do you believe you've specified the email sender address? I don't see any calls to [`setSender(Address address)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setSender(javax.mail.Address)). The `user` and `password` values given on the [`connect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Service.html#connect(java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) call is not the sender, but the authorization to use that mail server.

Comment: @Andreas, Bingo! Thanks!